# Issues with combining MultipartFile and other fields (415 – Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to upload file with Postman (`Post` request within its body a `attachment` key as `form-data`)

In my `@RestController` i try this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public String upload(@RequestParam("attachment") MultipartFile attachment) {
    return attachment.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

it works But when i try this with extra fields in some bean

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public String upload(@RequestBody FooBean bean) {
    return bean.attachment.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

With `FooBean`

```
public class FooBean {


    /* other properties */

    public MultipartFile attachment;

    public List<SubFoo> lists = new ArrayList<>();
```

I got `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type`

[image]

I know that if i separate them it will work but i don't want to because my list of `SubFoo` contains also `MultipartFile` fields

Comment: You aren't posting a body but a form, use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`.

Comment: of course i am posting a body in form-data format and even if i replace `@RequestBody` with `@ModelAttribute` the FooBean is empty

Comment: If you get a 404 then it has nothing to do with binding. So which is it? Is your model empty, the result wrong? Post HTML that makes up your form. None the less you should be using `@ModelAttribute` and not `@RequestBody`. \

Comment: no sorry it was a mistake i got an `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: Again you need `@ModelAttribute` and please add the HTML for the form.

Comment: I don't have an html i am using postman it's like i did an ajax post request

Comment: Then show your postman request.

Comment: I added it on the question

Comment: Make sure you have setters/getters on your object (not just public fields) and again use `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: thanks man a lot you were right i had to add setters/getters to use the with `@ModelAttribute`, write an answer so i can accept it and add the difference between `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` if it's possible